# Why do some elements form allotropes and others do not?

Tags: allotropes

I just studied in my chemistry class about the allotropes of carbon. But why does carbon form allotropes? Also why only carbon? Why do some elements form allotropes and others do not?

Comment: What kind of explanation do you expect? Elements are just different, much like people.

Comment: One can get some other allotrope of pretty much any element, if only try hard enough.

Comment: Your own reasoning – based on searching, reading and thinking – is supposed to be present to avoid the question closure for lack of own explicit  effort.  [How do I ask a good question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). // It seems you have skipped even basic searching.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/48751/allotropes-of-phosphorus?r=SearchResults&s=4|39.3424 ... https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141580/which-allotropes-of-sulfur-exist-naturally ... https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/28124/allotropy-in-nitrogen-and-bismuth-of-group-15